# How to upload images on React to Google Cloud Storage with Ruby as backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs, google-cloud-storage

I'm attempting to upload images from ReactJS to Google Cloud Storage with Ruby as my backend. I have attempted to send these images through an API I made with Rails, and then upload them directly into Google Cloud Storage through a gem known as 'google-cloud-storage'. These images are then called back through the API and to be displayed on my frontend which is ReactJS.

There seems to be a lot of issues in doing this, and one of which is a CORS problem when attempting to send an image through the API.

Does anyone have any suggestion or solution on how I can achieve uploading images from ReactJS to Ruby and then to Google Cloud Storage and then being able to call them and display on ReactJS?

Comment: Don't wire up yourself (unless you have something to gain by that): there are existing solutions out there. Try the Shrine gem: https://github.com/shrinerb/shrine or the ActiveStorage solution: https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html. I"m also positively sure there would be libraries in React which would make their incorporation even easier.

Answer (score 0):

To upload files into Cloud Storage with Ruby before code You have to prepare the bucket.

1. Create the deposit:
    gsutil mb gs : // [ YOUR - BUCKET - NAME ]

2.Set the default ACL of the deposit as public-read. This will allow users to see the 
  images they upload:
     gsutil defacl set public - read gs : // [ YOUR - BUCKET - NAME ]

3.Install the dependencies.

4.An implement the code.

You can follow the steps before mentioned in How to use Cloud Storage with Ruby[1] link.

[1]https://cloud.google.com/ruby/getting-started/using-cloud-storage